# Overwrite Current Workflow Instance Each Time Item is Edited

Tags: 2013, workflow, edit

I have the following `Edit Item` workflow set up on a list :

[image]

Where I need `New Review Date` to be updated to a year from today each time an item is edited. However, when I edit an item which already has this workflow running on it, a new instance of the workflow does not overwrite the current one.

I proved this by first creating an item, then approving it (which kicks off the edit item workflow), and then editing the item.

I can see that after editing the item, the workflow's Start Time has not changed, so it is still waiting for the initial edit's `New review Date` rather than overwriting the currently running workflow.

Is there a way of overwriting the currently running workflow each time an item is edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know this can't be completed using a designer workflow. I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure. What I was able to do to get around this is create a C# timer job that was installed as a WSP in CA. The timer job would run on the libraries location and look at the value specified and take action from there.

Any reason why you are using a workflow to do that calculation? I would do this in a calculated column and then evaluate that output. I stay away from doing math in workflows because I have to reproduce the workflow if edit needs to be made. Here is the formula for the calc column.
`=DATE(YEAR([Start Time])+1,MONTH([Start Time])+0,DAY([Start Time])+0)`

I would then write a timer job that would look at that value every hour or so and complete action on that. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh528519(v=office.14).aspx it should help.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, your Timer Jobs suggestion looks interesting and I will have to have a look at that. In the actual list I am indeed calculating the field at creation, but for testing purposes I've been trying absolutely everything! Thanks for the suggestsions

Comment: Very welcome Bassie. Respond if you run into any snags.